# Simplified verison of storing specific values inside an hashmap<String, Comparator>

Tags: java, mysql

So I made a hashmap to store player data, when someone first joins it executes a query and the data from the query result gets stored inside the hashmap.

What I'm wondering is there a good way to simplify what I've done? Are there better alternatives of what I'm trying to do. The reason why I did this is I don't want to constantly pull data from the MySQL database because that is extremely inefficient & slow.

So to the point what are some better & more efficient alternatives to what i'm trying to do.

My Comparator

```
public class Auth {

core plugin;

private String uuid;
private String name;
private int bits;
private String cult;
private String rank;
private String kit;

private int kills;
private int deaths;
private int blockstraveled;
private int blockbroken;

public Auth(String uuid, String name, int bits, String cult, String rank, String kit, int kills, int deaths, int blockstraveled, int blockbroken) {
    super();
    this.uuid = uuid;
    this.name = name;
    this.bits = bits;
    this.cult = cult;
    this.rank = rank;
    this.kit = kit;
    this.kills = kills;
    this.deaths = deaths;
    this.blockstraveled = blockstraveled;
    this.blockbroken = blockbroken;
}

public String getPlayerUUID() { return uuid; }
public String getPlayerName() {return name;}
public int getPlayerBits()
{
    return bits;
}
public String getPlayerCult() { return cult; }
public String getPlayerRank() { return rank; }
public String getPlayerKit() { return kit; }

//Stats
public int getPlayerKills() { return kills; }
public int getPlayerDeaths() { return deaths; }
public int getPlayerBlocksTraveled() { return blockstraveled; }

public int getPlayerBlocksBroken() { return blockbroken; }










@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Auth)) {
        return false;
    }
    Auth auth = (Auth) o;
    return Objects.equals(uuid, auth.uuid);

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(uuid);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Auth{" +
            "uuid='" + uuid + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", bits=" + bits +
            ", gang='" + cult + '\'' +
            ", rank='" + rank + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

My Auth Manager class

public class authmanager {

```
core plugin;
//public List<Auth> Auth = new ArrayList<Auth>();
public HashMap<String, Auth> auth = new HashMap<>();



public void saveUser(String uuid, String name, int bits, String cult, String rank, String kit, int kills, int deaths, int blockstraveled, int blocksbroken)
{

    this.auth.put(uuid, new Auth(uuid, name, bits, cult, rank, kit, kills, deaths, blockstraveled, blocksbroken));

}



public void saveCult(UUID u, String cult )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits(),
            cult,
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerRank(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKit(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken()));
}

public void saveRank(UUID u, String rank )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerCult(),
            rank,
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKit(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken()));

}

public void saveBits(UUID u, int bits )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits() + bits,
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerCult(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerRank(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKit(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken()));

}

public void saveKit(UUID u, String kit )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerCult(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerRank(),
            kit,
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken()));

}

public void saveKills(UUID u, int kills )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerCult(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerRank(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKit(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills() + kills,
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken()));

}


public void saveDeaths(UUID u, int deaths )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerCult(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerRank(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKit(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths() + deaths,
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken()));

}


public void saveBlocksTraveled(UUID u, int blockstraveled )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerCult(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerRank(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKit(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled() + blockstraveled,
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken()));

}

public void saveBlocksBroken(UUID u, int blocksbroken )
{
    this.auth.put(u.toString(), new Auth(
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerUUID(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerName(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBits(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerCult(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerRank(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKit(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerKills(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerDeaths(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksTraveled(),
            auth.get(u.toString()).getPlayerBlocksBroken() + blocksbroken));

}
```

}

Comment: stack overflow isnt a code review site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your individual methods like `saveCult()` will only be called on **existing** UUID, you could simplify by:

```
public void saveCult(UUID u, String cult ) {
   Auth a= this.auth.get(u.toString());
   if(a != null) { //SHOULD always be true, but who knows?
     a.setCult(cult);
     this.auth.put(u.toString(), a);
   }
}
```

Of cause, you'd need to a **setters** into your Auth class for this to work.